# can i use variable from csvdataconfig for source directory in directory listing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to upload file in HTTP request. I have used DirectoryListing plugin. It works fine. But, now i have a requirement where the http request should pick a file from different folder for each thread. I tried using file location in csv as below and provide variable name for source directory in Directory Listing Plugin. But, it doesnt seem to work. Can someone please help me with this?

[CSV file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCHua.png)

[DirectoryListing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRb7k.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use these elements this way, looking at [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) both are Configuration Elements it means that both are executed at the very beginning of the test.

The value from the CSV Data Set Config is being updated when a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) occurs, it explains the situation you're facing.

It's the same constraint like you cannot use 2 CSV Data Set Configs in "nested" mode, like use variable from 1st CSV Data Set Config as the input for 2nd CSV Data Set Config.

The workaround is going for [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) like it's described in the [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) article

Comment: Thank you! this was really helpful. I placed the file location in a txt file seperated with commas.  I used CSVRead as {__CSVRead(FilePath.txt,0)}${__CSVRead(FilePath.txt,next)} . But, the only issue is this gets all files in one thread. I have the folders as ABC1,ABC2,ABC3 etc. each one to be picked by a thread. Is there a way that i can use ThreadNum() function? I tried but, unsuccessful. Any inputs would be of great help. Thank you!

Comment: i think i was not using it the right way. I tried ${__CSVRead(FilePath.txt,${__threadNum})}